# Create variables from array and use them to call a method without knowing the variable names PHP

Tags: php, factory, factory-pattern

I have a factory pattern like this:

```
public function ViewFactory implements Factory {
    public function __construct() {

    }

    public static function Create($params) {
        //does not return variables, only extracts them
        $p = extract($params, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var_");

        //return object of view and pass in all variables extracted from array
        return new View($p);
    }

    ***
    ***
}

interface Factory {
   public function Create($params);
   ***
   ***
}
```

Im trying to use **extract** but it does not return variables I just have to access them using keys from associative array prefixed by **var_**. Is it possible to somehow return all values of array as variables comma separated and pass it into function?

My View Class:

```
class View {
   public function __construct($path, $parameters, $site_title) {
         ***
   };
}
```

Comment: You have them as something passible in your variable `$params` already. Why would want to do this?

Comment: I updated my question added code for View class. View constructor takes 3 parameters therefore when doing new View() I need to pass 3 parameters

Comment: `array_keys` to get the keys from the $params array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are asking for, but you can use [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) to create an instance of a class and pass it arguments from an array :

```
public static function Create($params) {
    $class = new ReflectionClass('View');
    return $class->newInstanceArgs($params);
}
```

Comment: will this return an object of View class? Meaning will my factory class behave the same way?

Comment: That is exactly what it does... it is the equivalent of @DanyCaissy answer if `$params` contains 3 elements.

Comment: it works, im not sure why you got -1. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm curious why I got down-voted as well any comment down-voter?

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the three of them to the view like this :

```
// This will reset the keys in the array, so the keys will now be [0] [1] and [2]
$p = array_values($p);

// Pass the values one by one
return new View($p[0], $p[1], $p[2]);
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution given a known number of arguments.

Comment: but I dont know number of arguments I want to reuse the functionality I will not always know the number of parameters thats why Im trying to avoid accessing items by its keys